# How to dynamically reference the very last cell in any given table?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a button that resets a given table to it's.. let's say *default size and formating*

I've spent some to get **Range.Resize** property right, but later found out that after *resizing* or *scaling down* the table it requires me to clean up everything that's left behind.

```
...
Sub Bt_clear_tb1()
    'ScreenUpdate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Resize and cleanup
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tab1")
        .Resize(.Range.Resize(10))
        .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange = _ ...
        .ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange = _ ...
    End With

    'Clear the rest | ---► Don't want it to be fixed ◄--- |
        Range("A11", "Q11").Select                   ◄--- |
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select ◄--|
        Selection.ClearContents                      ◄--- |

    'ScreenUpdate
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
...
```

Of course I got it to work manually on a fixed ranges, but I can't find a way to get the target range dynamically. So if I ever decided to move or resize it differently I wouldn't have to keep rewriting the code every time.

Almost thought I got it

like:

```
wb.ListObjects(1).Range.Cells(.Range.Rows.Count, .Range.Columns.Count).Offset(1,0).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

But it's not dynamic.. if I change ListObjects(1) to other table it still clears area below the first one.

Do you know any other way to somehow get the 'Range of an area below the table'?

~also please, excuse my terrible English.. I hope this is readable and somehow makes sense

Comment: Not your issue, but you may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint!

I found out the following solves my problem:

```
    Sub bt_table_1_clean()
    'ScreenUpdate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '@@@ Resize and cleanup
     Const ROWS2KEEP As Long = 20

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tab1")
        .Resize (.Range.Resize(ROWS2KEEP + 1))
        .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange = ...
        .ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange = ...
        .Range.Offset(ROWS2KEEP + 1).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    End With        

    'ScreenUpdate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

This is what I needed:

```
.Range.Offset(ROWS2KEEP + 1).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents
```

---

Comment: INstead of adding 1 to ROWS2KEEP two times you could have defined ROWS2KEEP as 21 and omit the two additions :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
Sub Bt_clear_tb1()
    Dim lSize As Long
    Const ROWS2KEEP As Long = 10
    'ScreenUpdate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Resize and cleanup
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        lSize = .ListRows.Count
        .Resize (.Range.Resize(ROWS2KEEP))
        .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange = "_ ..."
        .ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange = "_ ..."
        .Range.Offset(ROWS2KEEP).Resize(lSize - (ROWS2KEEP - 1)).ClearContents
    End With
    'ScreenUpdate
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: .Range.Offset(ROWS2KEEP).Resize(lSize - (ROWS2KEEP - 1)).ClearContents

throws Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: It ran fine for me, but perhaps your situation i slightly different from my testing setup :-)